# Is there a free alternative to Exception hunter?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm switching back and forth between Java and C# and one thing I miss while I'm coding in C# is the enforced exception checking (Although I admit I also find it really irritating sometimes while I'm coding in Java).

I'm aware that [Exception Hunter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/Exception_Hunter/index.htm) can help you track down what exceptions a piece of code might throw but is there a free/cheaper alternative? I can't really justify £200 for this kind of software addon as it's only an annoyance rather than a major problem.

Comment: Just let 'em go, man.  You can't control the world, you know.

Comment: But I want to. I really want to. :p

Comment: BTW, I +1 because I'm interested for the purposes of documentation, not because I believe I can handle each and every exception...

Comment: Handling every exception can lead to crazy amounts of code, but documenting an exception is like a softer version of Javas "throws" notation. I'd be happy if every API documented everything. they dont.

Comment: Looks like Exception Hunter has been discontinued

Comment: @OmarKooheji It's not about handling every exception, it's about looking at a piece of code, knowing that it could potentially throw a FileNotFoundException and catering for that specific case if it matters. Exception Hunter just lets you make informed decisions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Run the free [Microsoft Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) on your code. It will show all possible exceptions that can be thrown.

Comment: Looks like a great tool, thanks for the link.  Pity the commercial version only works with VS Team edition.

Comment: If you don't have the Team edition of VS, you can still use the tool from the command line. It generates HTML output I think.

Comment: This does not do static analysis to find thrown exceptions, it simply analyzes methods by calling them with heuristically determined parameters. It's designed for generating unit tests. http://exceptionalplugin.codeplex.com/ - this is a ReSharper plugin that'll do the job. Agent Johnson is a good complement to it - http://code.google.com/p/agentjohnsonplugin/

Comment: @Jake - Pex does do static analysis, and yes, it will find exceptions your code can throw. (And optionally, generate unit tests from checks and exceptions.)

Comment: As far as I could tell, it won't find exceptions in the framework or in third party code, however, which Exceptional seems to do fairly well.

Comment: Ah, good point. It finds exceptions in your code, but I don't know if it finds exceptions in external code.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand the enforced exceptions thing, I'm not sure how genuinely essential it is... for example, most *interesting* exceptions are those that you **wouldn't** normally include (or even expect). For example, I'm currently fighting what looks very much like a CLI bug in CF35, intermittently raising `MethodMissingException` from code that really does exist (emphasis: intermittently).

If you want to document your exceptions, use the `///<exception ... >...</exception>` markup. For other thoughts on this theme, perhaps see [Vexing Exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) (I wonder if [GhostDoc](http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/) might help any?)

Answer (score 0):

[Get Exceptional](http://getexceptional.com/) website is one possibility. Basic idea is that you create software and all exceptions are sent to this site to your account where you can pick them up. Of course it doesn't read your code and see what exceptions are there.

I don't know if there is C# library yet but the API is not too hard.