# C#: How to require error handling for a method?

Tags: c#, error-handling, compiler-warnings, preprocessor

I am writing a function for an API which I want to only be called from within a try statement so that developers can handle its custom exceptions.

Instead of just exaggerating the use of error handling in our documentation or using a #warning preprocessor directive, I was wondering if I could raise an error at compile time if the function is being called from outside a try statement?

Is is possible to do this?

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i'd be very surprised if that would work and i'd definitely consider it bad design. maybe if you'd be able to explain your case and reasons we could give you better options

Comment: I highly doubt this is possible.  You should be responsible for your code, and a consumer of your code should be responsible for theirs.  The best you can do is give them detailed errors and custom exceptions, which it sounds like you are.

Comment: Checked exceptions would be awful in C#. Imagine modifying a low-level method to use an array, and then having to add `throws IndexOutOfRangeException` to it and every method that directly or indirectly uses it. Or having to add `throws DivideByZeroException` to any method that directly or indirectly did an integer division using a variable divisor.

Comment: You might be able to do something close by having an `Func` parameter on your method that handles errors. E.g. it would be called like `MyAPI(someInputParam, error => { /* code to handle error */ });`

Comment: The code in question is an abstract planning system where developers are responsible for defining the scene description, agents, domain, and methods themselves. The system will raise an exception if a critical error in the plan is identified, for example a required object for the plan is missing in the scene description. A developer will want to handle these exceptions by calling subroutines on their agents to solve the issues at hand, like locating an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are refering to checked exceptions and they are not supported by C#.

Check @Reed Copsey's answer here:
[question]: [No force of exception handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972620/no-force-of-exception-handling)

Comment: Ah I see. Bummer. Thanks for the help!