# Find all catches where exceptions could end up

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I'm currently trying to find an error by reading code, since it is not reproducable at our end.
Nowadays it is easy to find definitions of members, methods, functions and all usages via Resharper, but in this instance I would like to have a function like: "From this line, give me all locations where an exception generated here could be caught"

Does such a function exist in Resharper, VS or any other place?

Comment: If exception is not handled in the method itself, then simply search for all references of this method. Won't work in all cases (e.g. for wpf xaml references, you have to use standard text search for method name in project files instead ).

Comment: That is my go to solution if I do not find a tool, but it would be much quicker and less frustrating to just be able to instead of references get the possible catch-block associated with any exception thrown at a certain location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread appears relevant: [Is there a free alternative to Exception hunter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654235/is-there-a-free-alternative-to-exception-hunter)

Specifically, you may find [Microsoft Code Digger](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fb5badda-4ea3-4314-a723-a1975cbdabb4) useful.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting tool indeed! I installed it, but could not get it to generate any output. The input/output is empty, and I cannot really figure out why.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it myself and it wasn't that fruitful, even when disabling the portable class library restriction. I think Sinatr suggestion may be the best alternative.